# Errors when upgrading ADAL from 2.22 to 5.0.5

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

I have a WPF client using ADAL to get tokens from ADFS to call our web-api. It uses the currently logged on windows user and authenticates against ADFS without any logon screen or prompts. However, after upgrading from `2.22.302111727` to `5.0.5` I'm having issues getting this to work. I want to upgrade to be able to target .NET Standard in my authentication library.

The existing code with `2.22` was

```
var ac = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);
var token = ac.AcquireToken(resourceURI, clientId, new Uri(clientReturnUri), PromptBehavior.Never);
```

When upgrading to `5.0.5` the API has changed slightly and I followed the documentation for [acquiring tokens silently using Integrated authentication on Windows (Kerberos)](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-Integrated-authentication-on-Windows-(Kerberos)) which results in

```
var ac = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);
var token = await ac.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceURI, clientId, new UserCredential());
```

this results in exception

> There was an error deserializing the object of type Microsoft.IdentyModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Internal.Oauth2.TokenResponse. Encountered unexpected character '>'.

which suggests that some HTML error message was returned.

And in the event log on the ADFS Domain Controller I see this:

> Microsoft.IdentityServer.RequestFailedException: MSIS7065: There are no registered protocol handlers on path /adfs/oauth2/token to process the incoming request.

I tried changing the code a bit to be more similar to the code I used for `2.22`:

```
var ac = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);
var token = await ac.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceURI,clientId,new Uri(clientReturnUri),new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Never));
```

This gave me exception

> The browser based authentication dialog failed to complete. Reason: The server or proxy was not found.

But, with this code I can see in the event log that a token was successfully created:

> A token of type 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2006/05/identitymodel/tokens/Kerberos' for relying party 'http://XXXXX.XXXXX.com/adfs/services/trust' was successfully authenticated.  See audit 501 with the same Instance ID for caller identity.

and

> An OAuth access token was successfully issued to client 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX' for the relying party 'http://XXXXXX/'.  See audit 500 with the same Instance ID for issued claims.  See audit 501 with the same Instance ID for caller identity.

What has changed in the way ADAL performs the authentication with Kerberos?
How can I make ADAL `5.0.5` do what `2.22` did sucessfully?